# URL mod_rewrite how to properly create syntax?

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following url:

```
http://example.com/files/101-info/index.php
```

My questions is:

1. Is it possible to remove the **101-** in the url?
2. Is it possible to rewrite the name in the address bar, but keep the file in the current location?

I would like to make the file appear to be at:

```
http://example.com/files/info/index.php
```

but actually remain in:

```
/var/www/htdocs/files/101-info/index.php
```

Here's what I tried, but I couldn't remove the **101-** and the redirect didn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([0-9]+)-([^\/]+)/(.+)\.php$ /$1/$2/$4 [R] // also tried [NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** *Keep in mind if you have other rules in your `.htaccess` that you have not mentioned in your question and you don't place the below rules at the proper place, it will not work as expected.*

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+files/[0-9]+-([^/]+)/([^\s\?]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /files/%1/%2 [R=302,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(files)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ /$1/101-$2/$3 [L]
```

First rule will remove the `101-`, the 2nd rule will accept the `101-` internally without having to change the folder name or the place your files are.

Change it from `[R=302,L]` to `[R=301,L]` once you confirm it is working.

Since you were previously using a redirect, your browser might be cached, so clear you cache and make sure to test the URL with a different browser until the cache of yours is cleared as it doesn't always happen after deleting it.

Comment: Hey thanks very much for this! It redirects just fine to the new path, although it appears the original file needs to be there too. Is this normal behavior? I assume there's no way to 'mask' the url, as in having the file remain at the original location but change the path in the browser. One more question, is it easy to swap out the `/files/` with a wildcard as well as `101-`?

Comment: @DIF it should lead to the file unless you have a folder called `info` as the rule to internally rewrite will not use folders or files that already exist, in other words `http://example.com/files/info/index.php` should not be an existent path/file. Yes, you can use `([^/]+)` for example.

Comment: Thanks your example really helped me understand this much better. One thing I'm stuck on though, is the last rewrite rule. How do I use the number not as a fixed constant? `/$1/101-$2/$3`, I tried `$1/$2-$3/$4` but it didn't work.

Comment: @DIF sorry what do you mean? The numbers represent the groups at the left side of the RewriteRule so for example the first one in my example is `(files)` which is `$1` and so forth for the other numbers.

Comment: The `101` part, how would I make that a wildcard instead of hardcoded so that it can be any number, but still go to the proper `/nnn-info/` directory?

Comment: @DIF there is no way to do that, once you remove it, there is no form of tracking to put it back there unless its present in the URL somewhere.